# error in passing the value with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I need some help with the error i keep getting, i got this from firebug

```
ReferenceError: ECOFATTYACHID is not defined
getBaseplate(ECOFATTYACHID,this.value)
```

and the js file looks like this,

```
function getThickness(projectName) {        

    var strURL="findThickness.php?project="+projectName;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('thicknessDiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('baseplateDiv').innerHTML='<select name="baseplate">'+
                    '<option>Select Baseplate</option>'+'</select>';                        
                } else {
                    alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}

function getBaseplate(projectName,thicknessVal) {       
    var strURL="findBaseplate.php?project="+projectName+"&thicknessValue="+thicknessVal;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('baseplateDiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                } else {
                    alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
```

and the php looks like this,

```
<?php 

$projectName = strval($_GET['project']); 

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT THICKNESS FROM COMPONENT_CUTTING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :projectName";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":projectName", $projectName);

oci_execute($result);

?>

<select name="thickness" onchange="getBaseplate(<?php echo $projectName?>,this.value)">
<option>Select Thickness</option>

<?php while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) { ?>

<option value=<?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?>><?php echo $row['THICKNESS']?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>
```

Please help me what am i doing wrong here ? from the first dropdown and second dropdown, im doing okay. So i get the projectName from the first dropdown and thickness from the second dropdown.

Comment: try this onchange="getBaseplate('<?php echo $projectName?>',this.value)"

Answer (score 1):

Please Use this

```
<select name="thickness" onchange='getBaseplate("<?php echo $projectName?>",this.value)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
 <select name="thickness" onchange="getBaseplate('<?php echo $projectName?>',this.value)">
```

now you are passing a string

Comment: should be like this 

`onchange='getBaseplate("<?php echo $projectName?>",(this.value));'`

Comment: what I meant was to make it as a string, not a variable

Comment: all the dropdown works fine but when i click submit, baseplate doesnt show any value 

`Array ( [projectName] => ECO-FATTY ACHID [thickness] => 28 [baseplate] => [quantityToCut] => 100 [text_remarks] => This is just a test run [submit] => Add Data ) `